# g++ cannot find library although it's there

Tags: c++, g++, antlr4, ld

I'm compiling some cpp files with:

```
$ ​g++ -c --std=c++17 -I/antlr4/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/ *.cpp
```

And everything goes fine:

```
$ ls -l *.cpp *.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   76637 Dec  1 14:33 Java8Lexer.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  370768 Dec  1 15:13 Java8Lexer.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  925012 Dec  1 14:33 Java8Parser.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5037896 Dec  1 15:13 Java8Parser.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     113 Dec  1 14:33 Java8ParserBaseListener.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2312 Dec  1 15:13 Java8ParserBaseListener.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     109 Dec  1 14:33 Java8ParserListener.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2304 Dec  1 15:13 Java8ParserListener.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     724 Dec  1 14:36 main.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  324360 Dec  1 15:13 main.o
```

When I try to link with a library, it fails:

```
$ g++ *.o -l/antlr4/runtime/Cpp/dist/libantlr4-runtime.so.4.9.3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/antlr4/runtime/Cpp/dist/libantlr4-runtime.so.4.9.3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is weird because the shared library *does* exist:

```
$ ls -l /antlr4/runtime/Cpp/dist/libantlr4-runtime.so.4.9.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1599624 Dec  1 14:28 /antlr4/runtime/Cpp/dist/libantlr4-runtime.so.4.9.3
```

Comment: Try:  g++ *.o -L /antlr4/runtime/Cpp/dist -lantlr4-runtime

Comment: @EricMarchand it works !! so remove the `lib` prefix and file suffix. Maybe you can post as a short answer for future users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the directory with option -L and the library file with its abbreviated form (no lib prefix, no .so.xxx suffix):

```
 g++ *.o -L /antlr4/runtime/Cpp/dist -lantlr4-runtime
```